# SvelteKit: Fetch API just one time

Tags: javascript, svelte, fetch-api, sveltekit

Inside `onMount` I have fetch API,
but I don't want to fetch that API every single time user tap on route on menu-bar.
Is there any solution for that (beside local storage)?

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let poem = [];
  let flag = false;

  onMount(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    poem = await response.json();
    flag = true;
  });
</script>


  {#if flag}
    <pre>{poem.plainText}</pre>
  {:else}
    <b>Loading...</b>
  {/if}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your `poem` in a [`writable` store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable) separate from the component and `fetch` it in the browser.

**Example**

```js
// lib/stores/poem.js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const poem = writable(null);

if (browser) {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    poem.set(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- routes/poem/+page.svelte -->
<script>
  import { poem } from '$lib/stores/poem';
</script>

{#if $poem}
  <pre>{$poem.plainText}</pre>
{:else}
  <b>Loading...</b>
{/if}
```